# Absolute convergence of a random variable in a countable space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am reading Jacod and Protter's *Probability Essentials* and I am struggling to understand the following string of inequalities:

[image]

where $L^1$ is the space of real valued random variables on ($\Omega$, $A$, $P$) for $\sigma$-algebra $A$ and probability measure $P$ that have a finite expectation.  Note that in this chapter, $A$ is defined s.t. $A$=$2^\Omega$ for a countable $\Omega$.

Specifically, I do not understand why the expecation would be "bifurcated" in to the sum of the two subsets of the image of $\omega$ such that $\lvert X( \omega) \rvert <1$ and $\lvert X( \omega) \rvert \ge 1$.

Edit: I am still struggling to see how I can bound $\sum_{\lvert X( \omega) \rvert <1} X(\omega)p_\omega$ or $\sum_{\lvert X( \omega) \rvert <1} \lvert X(\omega)p_\omega \rvert$ for that matter by $\sum_\omega p_\omega$ and $\sum_{\lvert X( \omega) \rvert \ge 1} \lvert X(\omega)p_\omega \rvert$ by $\sum_\omega (X(\omega))^2 p_\omega$.  Apologies for not making this clearer in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quirky. This should be starting like this:
$$\sum_{\omega}|X(\omega)|p_{\omega} = \sum_{|X(\omega)| < 1}\color{red}{|}X(\omega)\color{red}{|}p_{\omega} + \sum_{|X(\omega)| \geq 1}\color{red}{|}X(\omega)\color{red}{|}p_{\omega} \leq \ldots$$
(with the rest as is). The splitting is deliberate - it just allows to upper-bound each sum as is done.

Namely, $$\sum_{|X(\omega)| < 1}|X(\omega)|p_{\omega} \leq \sum_{|X(\omega)| < 1}p_{\omega} \leq \sum_{\omega}p_{\omega}$$ and, as $|x| \leq x^2$ when $|x| \geq 1$,
$$\sum_{|X(\omega)| \geq 1}|X(\omega)|p_{\omega} \leq \sum_{|X(\omega)| \geq 1}(X(\omega))^2 p_{\omega} \leq \sum_{\omega}(X(\omega))^2 p_{\omega}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Given absolute convergence, is it not correct as is in J&P? If this is true, how could the right-hand side of the first line be "less than" the left hand side?

Comment: The quirk is "forgetting" to take absolute values (now marked red by me).

Comment: So the absence of absolute values originally by J&P was not intentional, as the series is defined as absolutely convergent?

Comment: I think it's just a typo. But still it is an error (what if $X(\omega) \equiv -1$?).

Comment: Much appreciated, metamorphy.